# Adding Magento product on fly

Tags: magento-1.9

My store has around 30000+ products. I would like to add a new product on fly whenever a customer request for a particular custom product and send that product link to customer via email. I have seen post saying to add product programatically which i didn't understand how to use/run that script, also found a Cart2quote plugin which is way too expensive. So, can anyone help to achieve what is required?

Comment: will you please explain more about what exactly you want?

Comment: Ex: If a customer wants product X in "Black" color which is not available in my store. I should create that product instantly without adding it to database (as it is only required for that customer, no point in adding it to store) and send the product link to customer. And finally the customer should be able to book the product.

Comment: `as it is only required for that customer, no point in adding it to store` not possible. You have to create product in store to use cart and checkout functionality. You can delete that product after order success

Comment: so that's one part of the question, so how would i create a product on a fly(instantly), instead of filling all the information like default procedure.

Comment: refer http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/

Comment: well, i have said in my question i didn't understand how and where i should i use the script? a detailed step procedure could be very helpful

Comment: This extension is what exactly you are looking for https://magecomp.com/magento-email-cart.html